# WSL GUI apps run below 1 FPS. installing graphics drivers fixes the problem temporarily

Tags: performance, user-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run basic GUI applications in Ubuntu in Windows subsystem for Linux on my work laptop, I am lucky to get 1 frame per second. I was able to fix the problem by installing AMD's graphics drivers in Windows. However, after about a day (or maybe after a reboot) the GUI applications in Ubuntu return to running below 1 FPS.

Does anyone know what might be screwing with the graphics performance?